# XSD How to validate <any> with schema?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, any

If i use     `<xs:any processContents="strict"/>`     then how do I provide a schema for it?

message.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="messageNS"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="message">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="sender" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="content">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="strict"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

content.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="contentNS"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" />

</xs:schema>
```

message.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message xmlns="messageNS"
         xmlns:c="contentNS"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="messageNS message.xsd
                             contentNS content.xsd">     
    <sender>gfdgf</sender>
    <content>
        <c:text>asdsad</c:text>
    </content>
</message>
```

If i try to validate message.xml i get the following error:

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'c:text'.

I am using standard Java validator: javax.xml.validation.Validator;

Comment: What you have looks correct.  I suspect you may have an XSD location issue that has nothing to do with `<xsd:any/>`.   Are you sure you don't have an earlier warning in the logs that an XSD file cannot be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Schema` that is an aggregate of all the possible schema sources:

```
SchemaFactory f;
Source messageSource = // your message.xsd;
Source contentSource = // your content.xsd;
Schema schema = f.newSchema(messageSource, contentSurce);
Validator v = schema.newValidator();
```

Then use the `Validator`as usual.